# How to position objects in a 'radial-style' arrangement in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a script in Unity which creates a type of radial menu around an object the player is directly facing, but the number of buttons in the menu is a variable.

I've generated the angles to the main menu the objects are supposed to appear at easily enough...

```
            // int buttonCount = number of buttons
            float buttonWidth = 360 / buttonCount;
            for (int i = 1; i <= buttonCount; i++)
            {
                float maxAngle = buttonWidth * i;
                float minAngle;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    minAngle = 0f;
                }
                else if (i == buttonCount)
                {
                    minAngle = 360 - buttonWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    minAngle = buttonWidth * (i - 1);
                }
                float buttonAngle = (minAngle + maxAngle) / 2;
            }
```

...but now I'm trying to position the button objects at the corresponding angles around the central menu object and I don't know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function takes as parameters the object you want the buttons to go around, the player gameobject so that you can orient the new buttons toward the player, the angle you want the button to be at, and the radius (distance the button will be from the buttonCenter).  Its output is the button position in world space.  You can call it for each button you want to add.

```
Vector3 positionButton(GameObject buttonCenter, GameObject player, float angle, float radius) {
    //get the up and right vectors from the player object so we can orient the buttons
    Vector3 up = player.transform.up;
    Vector3 right = player.transform.right;

    angle = Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle;  //convert degrees to radians.  radians=degrees * 2pi / 360

    //cos(angle) give an x coordinate, on a unit circle centered around 0
    //sin(angle) is the y coordinate on the unit circle
    //take those values, multiply them by the up and right vectors to orient them to the player, 
    //multiply by the radius to move them the correct distance from the buttoncenter, 
    //and add the buttoncenter position so they circle around the correct point
    Vector3 buttonPos =buttonCenter.transform.position +  (radius * right * Mathf.Cos(angle)) + (radius* up * Mathf.Sin(angle));
    return buttonPos;
}
```

Comment: Tip: there is a `Mathf.Deg2Rad` constant (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks, need to brush up on my trigonometry

Comment: Oh by the way, you use Mathf.Deg2Rad like this... angle = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

Answer (score 0):

First, define an origin and distance for each button from it. As you have the angles, you can apply trigonometry which should allow you to find the coordinate of a point given an angle, distance and origin point. The point will be defined by cos() and sin() of the angle.

[Have a look at the 2nd section here](http://www.analyzemath.com/trigonometry/trigonometric_formulas.html)